# Null is not an object (evaluating 'RNFetchBlob.DocumentDir') using Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using Expo and try to download files using react-native-fetch-blob

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';

RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/images/img1.png')
  .then((res) => {
    let status = res.info().status;
  })
  .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
  })
```

There is an error occurs: **null is not an object (evaluating 'RNFetchBlob.DocumentDir')**

What i've already tried:

```
npm install --save react-native-fetch-blob
react-native link
```

```
npm install --save react-native-fetch-blob
react-native link react-native-fetch-blob
```

```
var RNFetchBlob = require('rn-fetch-blob').default
```

```
RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true react-native link
```

I cannot do [manually linking](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package), because i use expo and do not have /ios and /android folders.

Could anyone help, how to fix this issue? Is **rn-fetch-blob** work with Expo?

Comment: Did you restart the expo? If not then try again after restart expo.

Comment: It's just Ctrl+C and run ```npm start``` again? If so, i did it many times.

Comment: After installing new package, sometimes need to re-run project. Because expo server only recompile js part not your actual native part.. And is it works for you?

Comment: No unfortunately

Answer (score 12, accepted):

rn-fetch-blob doesn't work with expo.

> rn-fetch-blob implements native code, and so it cannot be used in expo
>   based projects. 
>   You would need to eject from expo

[Does rn-fetch-blob work with Expo?](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/517)

Answer (score 0):

add another .then before u use the result. Like this:
     const result= res.json()

If you need to see status, directly use res.status

Comment: it didn't help unfortunately. Even if i not use any RNFetchBlob function, only one string ```import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'``` causes this error

Answer (score 0):

Change the directory to: `ios` and run: `pod install` if you have run the app from XCode on real device, `re-run` it again.

Answer (score 0):

For react native after change `import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'` to `import { RNFetchBlob } from 'rn-fetch-blob';` in the node modules the error goes away.