# How do I save photo from firebase storage to phone Gallery with expo and react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a photo url and I want to download the photo to the phone storage. I store the photo on firebase so the url is something like `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/.../..***0e896313c`

As far as I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694623/null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-rnfetchblob-documentdir-using-expo) expo doesnt work with `rn-fetc-blob` so I started looking for alternative solutions. I thought I should use expo's [MediaLibrary](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/#medialibrarymediatype) but when I try to create asset with `await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);` it requires a local url with extension.

Am I missing something, or should I use some other library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `expo-file-system` to download the photo. It gives you a local uri after downloading the file. Then, use MediaLibrary to save the file to your gallery

```js
// Function to download the photo
const Download = async (uri) => {
  const downloadInstance = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
    uri,
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + "image.jpg"
  );

  const result = await FileSystem.downloadInstance.downloadAsync();
}
```

Your file would get downloaded in a directory whose uri would be in the `result` object.
Now use MediabLibrary to save the photo to the gallery.

If you just log `result.uri` you would get the local uri where your image has been downloaded. Now

```js
const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(result.uri);

MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("MyFolder", asset, false)
   .then(() => console.log('File Saved Successfully'))
   .catch(() => console.log('Error in saving file'));
```

By using above method your image would be saved in your Gallery in a folder called "MyFolder"